# How can i do this positioning of divs with FlexBox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i want to do this positioning of divs using flexbox, there are 3 divs , 2 must be in the row and the 3rd div must be in the bottom, all three divs are in the same big div
https://prnt.sc/utb29m

Comment: can you please edit your question and add "this positioning" code (HTML and CSS) in the question?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]. I suppose you haven't do any research to solve your problem, beacause if you do a simple google search you can find a lot of solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you wanted?

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat";
body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.wrap {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
}

.title {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.btn-show {
  margin-left: 2em;
}

.card {
  margin: 20px 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: #fff;
}

.container.show-border,
.element.show-border {
  border: 1px red solid;
  padding: 9px;
}

.content {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: calc(1vw + 1em);
}

@media (max-width: 375px) {
  .content {
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 0;
    text-indent: -9999999em;
  }
}
.container,
.element {
  padding: 10px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.col {
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.element {
  min-width: 100px;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.structure {
  min-height: 480px;
}

.structure-1 {
  flex: 1 55.5555555556%;
}

.a {
  flex: 1 50%;
}

.b {
  flex: 1 50%;
}

.structure-1-2-1 {
  flex: 1 20%;
}

.c,
.d {
  flex: 1 50%;
}

.e {
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.structure-2 {
  flex: 1 44.4444444444%;
}

.f {
  flex: 1 50%;
}

.structure-2-2 {
  flex: 1 50%;
}

.g {
  flex: 1 75%;
}

.h {
  flex: 1 25%;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .structure-1,
  .structure-2,
  .f,
  .structure-2-2 {
    flex: 1 100%;
    min-height: 480px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <h2 class="title">
    Complex layout with flex box
  </h2>
  <div class="container card">
    <div class="flex row structure">
      <div class="flex row structure-1">
        <div class="flex element a">
          <div class="content">
            A
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex element b">
          <div class="content">
            B
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex element e">
          <div class="content">
            E
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```